# I have a table with around 100 columns , is it possible for me to create a DAO class in hibernate with only the columns i need access to?

Tags: hibernate

I have a table with around 100 columns , is it possible for me to create a DAO class in hibernate with only the columns i need access to?

```
//@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@Table(name="PROJECTSETUP")
public class ProjectSetUp{
    @Id
    @Column(name="PROJECTNBR")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String NAME;

    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String DESCRIPTION;

    @Column(name="INFORMATION")
    private String INFORMATION;
}

Please let me konw.
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL constraints like `NOT NULL` may restrict you from making insertions, however you will be able to read data.

Source: Just tried on my table with 20+ columns and its corresponding Object, however beware if some of those columns capture mapping information even reading may be incomplete or infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about the phrase "columns i need access to?",is it like you have some condition(something like id>30 or columns after 20th record..or anyother),If you have something like that you can use criteria to get the result.

The Criteria interface provides methods to apply criteria such as retreiving all the records of table with some condition

Comment: i have 100 fields in database , i just need 5 of those fields , so my question is do i need to have all those 100 fields mapped in hibernate dao class or can i have only those 5 fields

Comment: If those 5 records are like the first 5 or the last 5 or between say (20-25),we can use criteria to only fetch those records and can work with them,

Comment: if you dont have any relation just some random 5 rows,you need to fetch all the records